# How to define the 'error'

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

I have `true data` $G$ and `wrong data` $F$.
Both are $n$ dimension vector.
$G\in   \{G_i| 0<G_i<255\}, i = 1:n$.

Because the wrong data is what I observe. I do not know how wrong it can be. If $F=G$, then there is no error.

What I am confused is as following. Suppose $G_3=0$ and $F_3=6$ ;
                                            $G_7=250$ and $F_7=256$.

If I use an error function like $e=\|G-F\|^2_2$,  $e_3=G_3-F_3=6$ ; $e_7=G_7-F_7=6$. Then $e_3$ and $e_7$ contribute the same to $e$. From my point of view, I am not sure I should treat them the same.

Because I also can think from $0$ to $6$, it changes $6/0$, infinate times. But from $250$ to $256$, it changes $6/250$ times.

The `wrong data` $F$ is generated by Gaussian Noise with $\mu$ zero mean and $\sigma……2$ standard deviation. That is

$G-F$~$\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$

How to evaluate the error?

Comment: You might look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thank you for your comment. I can not use 'relative error' since the denominate may be zero. I update my question. Could you please give me any opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what type of errors are important. If the various values come from measuring a length with a ruler, the base value doesn't matter, just the size of the error.  An error from 0 to 6 is just as bad as from 249 to 255.  In other situations a relative eror is more important and and error from 1 to 2 is just as bad as one from 127 to 254.  In that case you want to take the log of everything before you compute the error.  As you say, $0$ data plays havoc with this.

Comment: Hello. I update my question. Would you mind to check it again?

Comment: If you know the noise is additive Gaussian, you want the error function to be $\sum (G_i-F_i)^2$  You can prove this gives the best values for your fitted parameters.  This is discussed in section 15.1 of [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/)  Obsolete versions are free online

Comment: Thank you for your answer.